# How to prevent a div from moving around when another div is moved dynamically with jquery or javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click the menu on this page http://jsfiddle.net/3D8Sn/ the menu animates by moving up and down. Problem is, the `div` at the right of the menu also moves along with the menu. How do I prevent this and make the div remain in one position?

The HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="titlebar">
            <p id="applicationTitle">PageTitle</p>
            <div id="logoutLinkDiv">
                <a id="logoutLink" href="index.html" style="color:#5E5E5E">Logout</a>
            </div>

        </div> 
        <div id="accordionMenu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h3><span class="icon-home"></span>Menu1</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- we will keep this LI open by default -->
                <li class="active">
                    <h3><span class="icon-dashboard"></span>Menu2</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3><span class="icon-trap"></span>Menu3</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3><span class="icon-performance"></span>Menu4</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div> 

    </div> 


    <div id="theGrid"  style = "position: absolute;">
        <div id="jqxgrid">
        </div>
        <div id="eventslog" style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <div style="width: 200px; float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
                <input value="Remove Filter" id="clearfilteringbutton" type="button" />
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;" id='filterbackground'>Filter Background</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;" id='filtericons'>Show All Filter Icons</div>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left;">
                Event Log:
                <div style="border: none;" id="events">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>        


</body>
```

The CSS:

```
/**** Basic reset ****/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body 
{
    background: #BCED91; /*** background of entire page ***/
    font-family: arial, verdana;
}

/**** The Entire Menu ****/
#accordionMenu 
{
    background: #292929;
    width: 175px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #CCCCCC; /*main menu font color*/
    /**** Some cool shadow and glow effect ****/
    /*box-shadow: 
        0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
        0 0 200px 1px rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.5);*/
}

/******** Main Menu Button styles ********/
#accordionMenu h3 
{
    font-size: 11px;
    font-color: #D1D1D1;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.5px;    
    border-color: #141414;
    letter-spacing: 1px;

    /*fallback for browsers not supporting gradients*/
    background: #0A0A0A; 
    /*background: linear-gradient(#242424, #0A0A0A);*/
}

/********* Menu hover effect - NO USE HERE
#accordionMenu h3:hover 
{
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
*********/

/********* iconfont styles *********/
#accordionMenu h3 span 
{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/***** list items *****/
#accordionMenu li 
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

/***** links *****/
#accordionMenu ul ul li a 
{
    color: #CCCCCC; /*submenu font color*/
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 27px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;

    /**** transition for smooth hover animation ****/
    transition: all 0.15s;
}

/*hover effect on links*/
#accordionMenu ul ul li a:hover 
{
    color: #121212; /*submenu hover font color*/
    background: #FFB300; /* submenu hover background colour */
    border-left: 0px solid lightgreen;
}
/*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
#accordionMenu ul ul 
{
    display: none;
}
#accordionMenu li.active ul 
{
    display: block;
}
#titlebar { 
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height:40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    background: #0A0A0A;
    box-shadow: 
        0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
        0 0 200px 1px rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.5);    
}
#applicationTitle {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    color:#5E5E5E;
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    /*text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);*/
}

#logoutLink
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 97%;
    top: 13px;  
    right: 50px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;  
}
a.logoutLinkDiv:link 
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
#theGrid
{
    font-size: 13px; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    /*float: left;*/
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: -160px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

The Javascript:

```
/*jQuery time*/
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#accordionMenu h3").click(function()
    {
        //slide up all the link lists
        $("#accordionMenu ul ul").slideUp(200);
        //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
        if (!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
        {
            $(this).next().slideDown(200);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just as an FYI so you get a better response: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really a question asking for debugging help. I'm still learning how to position elements on a page and wanted to know how to handle such a situation. The downvotes were totally un-necessary. There was only so much to ask in the question. I don't know what else to elaborate. Please delete the question if it's so out of place on this website. The people who answered haven't yet got any upvotes, so deleting my question shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Matt Morrison has answered my question by helping me understand what I've done wrong in the structuring (which is exactly what I wanted). It's not debugging help.

Comment: its more that by providing code within the question itself the site continues to act as a self contained resource for future users, as well as current users being able to immediately see the root issue itself. The question ultimately is about code and a change thereto, so it likely will help greatly to provide some without total reliance on external resource. Note that the answers below were possible because of looking at the code in your fiddle link- that code should ideally be in your question (this is part of the sites question guidelines).

Comment: @SW4: I agree. That makes sense. Added the code too. Hope the downvoters remove the downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove margins from `#theGrid` and add positions to it:

```
 left: 300px;
 top: 100px;
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/3D8Sn/4/

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems the way you have styled the menu and the main content (in terms of their positioning) is a bit back-to-front, like you are putting the main focus on the menu and fitting the content around it, rather than instead making the menu fit to the content.

Try something like this perhaps: http://jsfiddle.net/3D8Sn/3/

It's just one possible way of doing it, which keeps your code as intact as possible with minimal changes. But as SW4 said, really you should provide more information as I'm not exactly sure which bits you do and don't want changed, and how those changes might fit into a larger proper design.

Relevant CSS changes:

- menu is positioned absolutely
- content is positioned normally, just with left padding to deal with the menu overlay

.

```
#accordionMenu {
    background: #292929;
    width: 175px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    position: absolute;
}

#theGrid {
    font-size: 13px; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 230px;
}
```